# How do I move the cursor to be just after the `>` character on the beggining of REPL evaluation?

Tags: motion, repl, slime

I am using Emacs and Slime to work on Common Lisp code and I would like to know the most efficient way to move the cursor to the beginning of the `REPL>` assessment.

For instance, modelling the cursor as "I", which keys should I press to move the cursor from this position:

```lisp
NIL
REPL> (defvar lista-history-entries (reverse (mapcar #'url (mapcar #'htree:data 
                                                                   (with-data-unsafe "I" (history (history-path (current-buffer)))
                                                                     (alex:hash-table-keys (htree:entries history)))))))
```

Into this position:

```lisp
NIL
REPL> "I"(defvar lista-history-entries (reverse (mapcar #'url (mapcar #'htree:data
                                                                   (with-data-unsafe (history (history-path (current-buffer)))
                                                                     (alex:hash-table-keys (htree:entries history)))))))
```

If I press `C-a` it brings me to the beginning of the line, which is only useful for my goal if the starting position is on the first line. If I press `M-a` it brings me to the NIL expression, just above the REPL. It is close and helpful. But I bet there is a way to be exactly at the beginning of the evaluation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slime REPL buffer is is REPL mode. You can get information about the mode with `C-h m`. That is useful in that it shows you the keymap for the mode, and among other things, you will see that `C-c C-p` is bound to `slime-repl-previous-prompt`. Here is an excerpt from the description:

```
REPL mode defined in ‘slime-repl.el’:
Major mode for interacting with a superior Lisp.
key             binding
---             -------

C-c     Prefix Command
C-j     slime-repl-newline-and-indent
RET     slime-repl-return
C-x     Prefix Command
ESC     Prefix Command
SPC     slime-space
  (this binding is currently shadowed)
,       slime-handle-repl-shortcut
DEL     backward-delete-char-untabify
C-<down>    slime-repl-forward-input
C-<return>  slime-repl-closing-return
C-<up>      slime-repl-backward-input
<return>    slime-repl-return

C-x C-e     slime-eval-last-expression

C-c C-c     slime-interrupt
C-c C-n     slime-repl-next-prompt
C-c C-o     slime-repl-clear-output
C-c C-p     slime-repl-previous-prompt
C-c C-s     slime-complete-form
C-c C-u     slime-repl-kill-input
C-c C-z     slime-nop
C-c ESC     Prefix Command
C-c I       slime-repl-inspect

M-RET       slime-repl-closing-return
M-n     slime-repl-next-input
M-p     slime-repl-previous-input
M-r     slime-repl-previous-matching-input
M-s     slime-repl-next-matching-input
```

`C-h m` is one of the first things I do when exploring an unfamiliar mode.

Answer (score 2):

`backward-sexp`, bound to `C-M-b` by default`, would do it. Of course, if you’re nested inside several s–expressions then you would need to press it multiple times.

So perhaps you want `beginning-of-defun`, bound to `C-M-a`, instead.